# What book has a space station orbiting a sun

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I remember a few details of the book I'm looking for. It is a space station in close orbit to the/a sun. Only children on board who are the children of the adults. But the adults were criminals and are now dead/gone. The adults, not sure if criminals or others maintained the station and with them dead/gone things start to fail. One thing in particular I remember is the one kid wearing weights everywhere even exercising and can't remember why he has to or at least couldn't think of a reason to take them off. I think the children thought themselves responsible for their parents crimes as well.

"Anvil of the sun" seems to be a stand out idea for the name of the book but have not managed to find anything yet. Thank you if you are able to help at all.

Comment: If you're sure "Anvil" is in the title, [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi) has good title search. Unfortunately, it doesn't generate linkable pages, but it's easy enough to use. Just be sure to select "Fiction Titles" for your search type. You'll get about 28 titles.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks for fixing my comment!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will try that and wiki the results to see if any of them match. Will check out "Anvil of Stars" but the wiki description does not seem correct. Thank you though.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191179/sf-novel-featuring-children-on-a-spaceship

Answer (score 6):

There's a Greg Bear novel called *Anvil of Stars*. It has a similar title, and kids on a space station, but no criminals that I remember. Here's what [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Anvil_of_Stars) says:

> **Anvil of Stars** (1992) is a book by Greg Bear and a sequel to *The Forge of God*. In the novel, volunteers from among the children saved from the recently destroyed Earth are sent on a quest by a galactic faction called "The Benefactors" to find and destroy "The Killers", the civilisation who sent the killer probes in the first place. The Law that the Benefactors subscribe to requires the "Destruction of all intelligences responsible for or associated with the manufacture of self-replicating and destructive devices." The book is written entirely from the point of view of a central character, Martin Gordon, who is the son of a central character in *The Forge of God*, Arthur Gordon.